# Someone Copied Our Site Code (Including Analytics) and Put Adult Content on It

Tags: wordpress

Someone copied our WordPress based website and put it on another server and added adult content on it. It also includes our Google Analytics code so the traffic to this site also shows on our analytics data.

Please some one suggest how to remove it and why did someone do this?

This site also includes our Google doubleclick code so how can that harm our ad services?

Comment: As someone removed the URLs, now it is difficult to understand the question and exact situation.

Comment: The URLs are in no way necessary to understand what's going on here. Please don't link to a site which you *know* is potentially malicious at worst, and contains pornography at best.

Comment: It's easy to know what happened: someone liked your design, downloaded it, changed the content and uploaded again, and forgot to change the Google code.

Answer (score 10):

You could write an abuse email (ISP) to the hoster of this copied website (Domain Whois).
The hoster should be aware about legal regulations (Copyright) and should write to the owner to put it offline.

Normally you should follow the steps below:

- Write to website owner (Domain owner) to put site down
- If you do not get any response contact the ISP of this website and report abuse about it. Be sure to provide your website link, their website link and a description. If you're not sure about the Hosting provider may consult: http://www.whoishostingthis.com
- If Page is already listed on search engines contact them to remove this page.
- If you do not get any response, contact your lawyer (specialised lawyer)

Comment: I have already wrote an email to domain owner but so far they haven't responded.

Comment: Do not write to the domain owner. Write directly to the ISP or TECH-C or ZONE-C Entry on Domain whois

Answer (score 8):

You can exclude the hostname sending data to your profile by setting up an exclude filter.

Alternatively, it might be better if you set up just an include filter for your own hostname to ensure you don't see anything like that in the future.

Google Analytics Filters - you might want to set up a rule/filter to "Include only traffic from the domains equal to" YourDomain.net.

**and also:**

**How to Protect Yourself**

All you need is a simple filter. It will only include traffic on your domain, protecting yourself from any data corruption when people hijack your Google Analytics Property ID.

To find your filters:

Go to your Google Analytics standard reports
Click on the “Admin” button in the top right
Click on “Filters”
Click “+ New Filter”
Then use these settings for your filter:

Select “Create New filter for Profile”
Name your filter with something snazzy like “Hacking Defense”
Select “Custom Filter”
Select “Include”
For the Filter Field, select “Hostname”
If your site is example.com, you would define the filter pattern as “example.com” and make sure to include a “\” before any “.”
Pick “No” for case-sensitive

the answers are here:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28994/someone-else-is-using-our-google-analytics-tracking-code-number-what-do-we-do

https://blog.kissmetrics.com/protect-analytics-from-hacking/

Comment: also you can change your google analytic ID, this is the last  and bad way.

Comment: Will this filter prevent the OP from being alerted someone has copy/pasted his site?